# Is it possible to stop certain apps from updating via Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate

A friend of mine updated a certain app and I don't like the choices the devs made. I'd rather stay on the current version. I know that I can set Google Play to not update apps automatically.

Thing is, I love being able to press <kbd>UPDATE ALL</kbd> to update all my apps with one press. Except for this app...

How can I make sure that this app does not appear in the Google Play updates section anymore?

Comment: No you can't remove it from update all list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you don't want auto update or you if you want to remove it from the update all list. All apps will appear in the update all apps list. You can not remove them from that list.

To remove from auto update go to `Google Play Store > Find the app you don't want to auto update > Select the 3 dots` on the top right of the screen and deselect auto updates.

Comment: So, if I disable auto-update for an app individually by following that last line, does it mean that if there is any app update pushed to Play store, I won't be notified about it and if I check Update All list, that app won't be visible there. Am I correct?